# Searching by the Text property in Treeview.Nodes

Tags: vb.net, nodes

I have a WinForm tree view using VB.NET (property is named "*tvwAcct*") where I would like to be able to search through all the existing nodes with a given string ("*txtName.Text*"), and if it already exists, to give the user a Message box warning to stop duplicate entries. It needs to be able to search all parent nodes and also child nodes. My current tree structure is as follows:

> Bank account name
>
> -> Sub-account name 1
>
> -> Sub-account name 2
>
> ->  Sub-account name 3

I have looked at [MSDN.Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenodecollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx) and can see that the **Nodes.Find** method exists.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub txtName_Validating(eventSender As Object, eventArgs As CancelEventArgs) Handles txtName.Validating
    Dim Cancel As Boolean = eventArgs.Cancel

    ' [ other 'if' conditions here ]

    If tvwAcct.Nodes.Find(txtName.Text, b).Length > 0 Then
    MyMsgBox("Sorry, this cost centre/bank account already exists.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
End If
```

Whilst debugging using the [Watch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee440547(v=office.12).aspx) feature for the **tvwAcct.Nodes** property, I can see that this code logic works, but appears to be comparing against the "Name" property of the Node, rather than the "Text" property. Eg. If I type something along the lines of "*NODE0000*" in my "*txtName*" box and try to leave, the error message will successfully appear and fail the validation.

So, I know it works, but it's not looking at the correct property.
Does anyone know how I can force it to look for Text rather than the Name?

Comment: You can't force it to do anything else than what it was programmed to do.  You can however assign the TreeNode.Name property so that Find() will become useful.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for this, that seems reasonable. I don't suppose you could kindly elaborate this comment as a potential answer please? I'm not experienced enough to understand your thoughts.

Comment: @HansPassant What I mean to say, is you mentioned "You can however assign the TreeNode.Name property so that Find() will become useful." I am unsure what this means, how to interpret, or make this useful to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add nodes to your TreeView, make sure to set the "name" of the Node along with the Text.

```
tvwAcct.Nodes.Add(txtName.Text, txtName.Text)
```